# How to access existing SharedPreference by another android app

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences, encrypted-shared-preference

I'm having an app which is already live on play store and whole data of that app is stored in `EncryptedSharedPreferences`. I'm using `androidx.security.crypto` for the `SharedPreferences`. Now I'm going to have a new app on play store with different package name. So I want to access whole data of that app and transfer into new app. I tried using `sharedId` but it always returns null to me. Below I'm mentioning the custom shared preferences class what I'm using in an existing app.

```
class SharedPrefUtils(context: Context) {
private val keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC
private val masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec)
private val PASS_KEY = context.getString(R.string.pass_key)
private val sharedPrefs = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
    PASS_KEY,
    masterKeyAlias,
    context,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
)
```

So I want to know whether it's possible to access this type of data or not. If not, then what alternatives I can have.

Thanks.

Comment: If you could do that you could read all such data from my app too. It's private storage.

Comment: Generally yes, but one still can expose them; preferably while using the same signature.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid SharedUserId is deprecated. You can create an IPC between both apps and share the data. however, it needs changes to your existing app.

Comment: @blackapps I agree with you but sometimes we face an unnecessary requirement. And this is that stage.

Comment: You can extend ContentProvider class and serve your shared preference files/data with it to other apps.

Comment: You can copy your shared preferences files to a storage location that is accessable by other apps.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If not, could Android Account Manager be used for what you want to achieve? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager

Comment: @IshitaSinha I had to find solution for my existing apps but it didn't look possible as package names are also going to be updated.